# How to get Jquery web carousel fit on my phonegap app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, flexslider

Well i trying to get a web jquery carousel to my phonegap app. I look for many possibilities but unfortunately can't find a real resizable carousel that can go on with any devices android or iphone..

I taked a look at Jcarousel http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ and Flexslider http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ but can not work as well as it should on mobile devices

can anyone help me please ?